# Axios, fetch() setting request headers into Access-Control-Request-Headers instead of separate headers

Tags: javascript, http, cors, http-headers, fetch-api

I am trying to make a GET request with some custom headers from a react application.

This is the code for the axios interceptor:

```
addCaptchaHeaders(captcha, sgn, exp) {
    // remove the old captcha headers
    if (this.captchaHeadersInterceptor !== undefined) {
      this.removeCaptchaHeader();
    }
    // Sign new captcha headers
    this.captchaHeadersInterceptor = this.httpClient.interceptors.request.use(
      config => {
        // Add headers here
        config.headers.common._captcha = captcha;
        config.headers.common._sgn = sgn;
        config.headers.common._exp = exp;
        return config;
      },
      error => {
        // Do something with request error
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

These are the response headers for the preflight request:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, content-type, accept, authorization, _captcha, _sgn, _exp
Content-Length: 0
Server: Jetty(9.3.24.v20180605)
```

These are the request headers for the preflight request:

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,sl;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers: _captcha,_exp,_sgn
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:8086
Origin: http://localhost:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.92 Safari/537.36
```

The headers for the actual request after the preflight one are the same. So `Access-Control-Request-Headers: _captcha,_exp,_sgn` instead of custom request headers.

Thinking it was an axios configuration issue I made the same request using fetch:

```
fetch(
      "http://localhost:8086/podatki/parcela/search?parcela=1727&count=50&offset=0",
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          _captcha: res,
          _sgn: sgn,
          _exp: exp
        }
      }
    );
```

The result is the same.

Is this an issue with the browser-server communication? If so are there some things missing from the response headers?

Doing the same request with postman works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response headers for the preflight as shown in the question indicate the server’s not sending back the [`Access-Control-Allow-Methods`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/TTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Methods) response header.

For the browser to consider the preflight a success, it needs the server  response to include both the [`Access-Control-Allow-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers) and [`Access-Control-Allow-Methods`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/TTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Methods) response headers.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you check the headers? Chrome dev tools indeed displays them like that, but only when the request fails to load (due to lack of 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header - in this case it fails even if the server returns 200 - or for any other reason)

Comment: Yes, it was chrome. The problem was indeed with the server - after all the response headers were set correctly the network call works.